# Align grid child at the bottom of grid

Tags: css

I have a grid

```
#featuredRestaurantSection {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(100px, 1fr));
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(100px, auto);
  -webkit-column-gap: 10px;
  column-gap: 10px;
  row-gap: 2em;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

I have 3 divs inside that e.g. a1, a2 a3. I want that div.a3 should always be positioned at the bottom of grid. Because a1 & a2 can have variable height and it look odd.

Is it possible and how.

Thanks

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 3):

The following should do the trick

```css
#featuredRestaurantSection {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(100px, 1fr));
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(100px, auto);
  -webkit-column-gap: 10px;
  column-gap: 10px;
  row-gap: 2em;
  padding: 10px;
}

.a3 {
  align-self: end;
}
```

```html
<div id="featuredRestaurantSection">
  <div class="a1">Item 1</div>
  <div class="a2">Item 2 - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ducimus magni ad, tenetur pariatur commodi minus libero tempora.</div>
  <div class="a3">Item 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: a1, a2, a3 are inside single grid container/child. Every grid child has its own a1, a2, a3. And height of a1, a2 can vary due to varying amount of text

Comment: "I have a grid. I have 3 divs inside that e.g. a1, a2 a3. I want that div.a3 should always be positioned at the bottom of grid." If you need something different, you should adjust the question and include a better code example.